# plot bar by x and y coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a hanging rootogram in python. I know there is already a question on this here: [How to plot a hanging rootogram in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252879/how-to-plot-a-hanging-rootogram-in-python)
but my approach is a bit different.

In my pandas dataframe the data is organized like this:

**x**: is the x axis point, here 1,2,3,...

**height** : is the height of the bar

**y**: starting point for plot

**line**: the bordering line for each bar

What I want is a bar for each point *x*, that starts at *y* and is of *height* . The end of the bar is then at *line*

this is what I got so far:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects = ax.bar(df['x'], df['height'] - df['y'], 1)
ax.plot(df['x'], df['line'], color='r')
ax.set_ylim([-10,15])
```

[image]

what I want is something like this:

[image]

Comment: I thinks that the solution of the hanging rootogram applies here. You need to iterate over each of your bar (patches) and move them so the y-positions match the value of line at the same position.

Comment: @jrjc No, of course that linked solution works, but the solution is much easier, see my answer below.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in this case is much easier than in the linked question. You just need to use the `bottom` argument of `plt.bar`.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(12)
line = np.sqrt(np.sinc(np.sqrt(x/2.))**2)*2+0.35
y = np.random.rand(12)-1
#height is redundant
height = line-y

plt.bar(x, height, bottom=y, edgecolor="k" )
plt.plot(x,line, color="#dd0000")
plt.plot(x,y, marker="o", ls="", color="k")
plt.ylim(-2,3)
plt.show()
```

[image]